# Global variable not working in php

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am facing some errors with use of global variables.
I defined a $var in global scope and trying to use it in functions but it not accessible there. Please see below code for better explanation:

File a.php:

```
<?php

  $tmp = "testing";

  function testFunction(){
     global $tmp;
     echo($tmp);
  }
```

So a bit about how this function is called.

File b.php:

```
<?php
  include 'a.php'
  class testClass{
    public function testFunctionCall(){
        testFunction();
    }
  }
```

The above 'b.php' is called using:

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method);
$method->invoke();
```

Now the desired output is 'testing' but the output received is NULL.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you accessing this function?

Comment: Is this function defined in a class? If yes, declare $temp as static variable and  use self::$tmp instead of using it like global variable.

Comment: You are using function with "protected" property. use "public"

Comment: You need to start a new question as your `recently` edited question is completely different from what we all have answered.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Sure will do that. Sorry for the question not being formulated properly in the 1st place.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: So it stackoverflow wont let me start a new question saying it is a repeated question. So could you help me out with this. I have done a work around but i still dont understand why it wont work.

Comment: @shanilpuri, Why don't you use call-by-reference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed calling your function and also remove the **`protected`** keyword.

Try this way

```
<?php

  $tmp = "testing";

  testFunction(); // you missed this

  function testFunction(){  //removed protected
     global $tmp;
     echo($tmp);
  }
```

Same code but using **`$GLOBALS`**, gets you the same output.

```
<?php

$tmp = "testing";

testFunction(); // you missed this

function testFunction(){  //removed protected
    echo $GLOBALS['tmp'];
}
```

Comment: Already tried this. It is working fine in 5.3.x but causing issues in 5.4.10

Comment: @shanilpuri, Can you try the edited answer with `$GLOBALS` on your 5.4.10 ?

Comment: Tried using $GLOBALS also. Still the same NULL output.

Answer (score 1):

This protected function can't access the variable. So use by removing **protected**.

```
<?php

  $tmp = "testing";

   function testFunction(){
     global $tmp;
     echo ($tmp);
  }
```

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: yes that was put in the question by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

protected functions need to be in a class like this:

```
 Class SomeClass extends SomeotherClass {

   public static $tmp = "testing";

   protected function testFunction() {

      echo self::$tmp;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem here.
As $GLOBALS is seen within any function I used this :

```
<?php

  $GLOBALS['tmp'] = "testing";

  function testFunction(){

     echo( $GLOBALS['tmp'] );
  }
```